# Monte Carlo double integral with variable limit

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, monte-carlo

my question is how to solve the following problem using the Monte Carlo Integration method:

$P = \int_a^b\int_x^d g(x,y) dydx$

Most of the tutorials I read concentrate on specific limits, just like $P = \int_0^3\int_0^5 g(x,y) dydx$,  which can be easily solved by uniformly sampling and averaging.

However, few of them refers to above problem.

Thank you!

Comment: The domain is a quadrilateral in (x,y).  Pick points uniformly in that domain, then evaluate g and average.

Answer (score 0):

To pick a point from a uniform distribution in the quadrilateral, first choose $x$ in the interval $(a,b)$ using a density function $f(x)=k|d-x|$, where $k$ is computed by $\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx=1$.
Choose $y$ uniformly in the interval $|x,d|$.

To evaluate the integral compute $h=g(x,y)$ at the chosen $(x,y)$.  If $x\le d$ add $h$.
However if $x\gt d$ subtract $h$.  This is necessary because $\int\limits_d^b\int\limits_x^d g(x,y)dydx=-\int\limits_d^b\int\limits_d^x g(x,y)dydx$, since the lower limit should not exceed the upper limit for $y$ integral.

Comment: Ordinarily you would have $a<b<d$ so that this is describing a triangle in the normal orientation.

Comment: @ian Unfortunately, the proposer did not specify that condition, so I felt it necessary to take that possibility into account.